# Could not find or load main class in a simple java project

Tags: java, package, javac

I have created a simple java project "DesignPatterns".
I created a file FacadePattern.java with the path being `~/DesignPatterns/Structural/FacadePattern/FacadePattern.java`

My `FacadePattern.java` class,

```
public class FacadePattern {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // Some code
    }
}
```

But my editor (VSCode) gives me an error at the start of the file:
`The declared package "" does not match the expected package "Structural.DecoratorPattern"`

So upon clicking on quick fix, it added `package Structural.FacadePattern;` in the first line.

So the final code became

```
package Structural.FacadePattern;

public class FacadePattern {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // Some code
    }
}
```

But when I compile the above file using the command

```
javac FacadePattern.java && java FacadePattern
```

It is giving me the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class FacadePattern
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Structural/FacadePattern/FacadePattern (wrong name: FacadePattern)
```

After searching a lot in the internet, I ran the following command:

```
javac -sourcefile ~/DesignPatterns FacadePattern.java && java FacadePattern
```

But no use, I am getting the same error.

Can anyone explain why my editor gave an error but code ran successfully before? and why wont it compile after adding "package Structural.FacadePattern;" line? and what is -sourcefile parameter in javac command? and how to run the code with successfully without errors in editor as well as the terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Stick to naming rules. Package names should be lowercase only. In your case, it should be `package structural.facadepattern;`
2. Run the 'correct' class. Because your class is not inside 'the base folder' aka the 'default package', you have to prefix the class with its package name: `java Structural.FacadePattern.FacadePattern` or rather `java structural.facadepattern.FacadePattern` if you use the proper case for packages.

Comment: Hi @JayC667, I tried both the ways you suggested. The first one gave me ClassNotFoundException: Structural.FacadePattern.FacadePattern and the second one (after renaming all the folders), ClassNotFoundException: structural.facadepattern.FacadePattern.

Comment: My bad, I was running java command inside the facadepattern package, after changing the path to root folder, it worked! Thanks a lot!